# yii\jui\datepicker changes formats for days below 13

Tags: php, jquery, yii, datepicker, yii2

**I'm using yii\jui\Datepicker in my view**. When I select a date, the date string output is correct. When I click on the form submit, the date in the view page is also perfect.

I have a behavior that alternates the format from Y-m-d to d/m/Y and back when you are taking the date from the form to the database and back. All these appear to be working perfectly.

**The problem I face** is that when try to edit the form, the Datepicker displays the date in a format like m/d/Y and when the dropdown comes it is in fact d/m/Y but the date in incorrect.

For example, the correct date is 12/02/2017 and this date is correct in the database and in the view (in their respective formats) but when editing the form, it displays as 02/12/2017 and the dropdown has 2nd of December selected. 05/01/17 also displays as 1st of May in the Datepicker but correctly as 5th of January in the view and database.

Even stranger, this only happens for days below the 13th. If it is set to 13/01/2017 it consistently displays as 13th of January all through. 
My formatter settings for dateFormat and dateTimeFormat are "php:d/m/Y" and "php:d/m/Y H:i:s". I have no "dateFormat" options in my Datepicker options though even that set to the formats above, it makes no change.  Also, an echo of the model attribute, on the form, displays the date in the correct format. It is probably something very simple but I am at a loss as to what is wrong here.

DatePicker configuration in the view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'complete_by')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), ['dateFormat' => 'php:d/m/Y'] ); ?>
```

Formatter settings:

```
    'formatter' => [
        ...
        'dateFormat' =>  'php:d/m/Y', 
        'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d/m/Y H:i:s',
        ...

    ],
```

Comment: I searched by the way, but the only other question with a similar question I found, does not have an answer that solves my problem. I tried them.

Comment: any live links to the app

Comment: Sorry, not at the moment. This is all on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone faces the same problem. I eventually switched to kartik\date\DatePicker instead. I literally, just replaced the classname and this worked!